# how to write mongo query like WHERE student_id AND ( (name like %xyz%) OR ((department like %xyz%)) OR (city like %xyz%) )

Tags: mongodb

How to write a query in mongodb, 
    WHERE student_id AND (
    (name like %xyz%) 
    OR ((department like %xyz%)) 
    OR (city like %xyz%)
    )

Comment: are you sure about WHERE student_id AND ( (name like %xyz%)

Comment: Its only where clause which is i written in mysql

Comment: Can you please post your full query ?

Comment: I want equivalent query for mongoDb

Comment: Before asking such question have you read the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) and trying by yourself ? If so and you run into trouble, describe precisely your problem. If not, give it a try

Comment: SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE student_id BETWEEN 25 AND 1001 
AND (
(name like '%xyz%') 
OR ((department like '%xyz%')) 
OR (city like '%xyz%')
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below given should serve as your mongo syntax for the SQL query you mentioned

```
 db.student.find(  { $and : [  , ,  { $or : [  { name : /.*xyz.*/}, 
 { department : /.*xyz.*/}, 
 { city : /.*xyz.*/} ] }  
 ] }  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a mongo equivalent to sql DB query. If it is simple you can try 
[SQL to Mongo](http://www.querymongo.com/)

For the query that you have asked. Try

```
    db.student.find({name:/xyz/,department:/xyz/,city:/xyz/, student_id : { $gte:25, $lt: 1001 }})
```

Comment: SQL to Mongo will not provide a solution sharply is what I have heard. Is that true ?

Comment: It has it's own limitations, like a complex query can not be answered by SQL to Mongo